# Why does Y. Moshe Vardi use this specific matrix when estimating source-destination traffic intensities with EM algorithm?

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, probability-distributions, algorithms, approximation-algorithms

Sorry for the verbose title, but the question is super specific. If you happen to know a site better suited for these types of question, feel free to direct me.

The article to which I am referring to is

- Vardi, Y. 1996, *Network tomography: Estimating source-destination traffic intensities from link data*, Journal of the American Statistical Association. **91** no. 433. (1996) S. 365-377. doi:[10.1080/01621459.1996.10476697](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1996.10476697).

At the end of the article Vardi proposes a variant of the [EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) to estimate the traffic intensities from the observed data. Part of the algorithm uses, for some reason, a matrix $B$ that is formed from the neighbourhood matrix $A$ of the directed graph, by taking the element-wise products of all rows of $A$. This matrix $B$ is then used in the EM algorithm (see equations (28) and (29) in the paper) to what I presume scale the link-wise covariances of of the data. This scaling happens by dividing an $i^{th}$ covariance with the dot product of the $i$th row of the matrix $B$ with the parameter vector $\lambda$ that is being estimated.

What I am unsure about is that depending on the type of graph $G$ we are dealing with, the matrix $B$ could end up having zero rows, which in turn result in division by zero. Therefore, i.) can such errors be avoided? ii.) Is there a more "robust" estimation algorithm to be used? iii.) is the algorithm presented applicable to only certain types of graphs?